# C# MVC Creating a timer based auto-logout with jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, timeout

How do I create an jquery script to automatically log out the user after a set period of inactivity?  Or is there a jquery plugin that does this? It would need to do something like:

1. Create timer with setTimeout (eg for 30 mins)
2. Reset the timeout every time the user interacts with the page
3. After the setTimeout expires, use ajax to call the /logout action on the server (asp.net mvc)
4. Show a modal/lightbox dialog telling the user to login again

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier managing this on the server side then once timer expires redirect them to a page with the modal / lightbox popup?

Comment: Agreed. And even then, are you sure you want to manually log them out after a fixed period of time? Doesn't the expiry for the forms authentication ticket (sliding expiration) serve this purpose?

Comment: @tim The main part that I'm not sure how to do is #2 Reset timer to 30 mins after any user action.  How would I concisely detect any action at all?

Comment: @rpm yes the forms auth does do that.  But what happens is that if the user idles then clicks something, the form auth is expired and they get redirected to the login page instead - and they say "wtf? I just clicked the save button, why do I have to login?"  So this is a way to let them know that they have been logged out in a more gentle manner.

Comment: You could always write a really light ajax service which polls MVC to see if the timer has expired then writes to a hidden field etc. Then javascript could monitor this field, if it signals user session is expired, show the modal? What do you think? That's probably easiest method I can think of if you want to do it all on the client side and handle browser closing etc

Comment: That's over complicating it.  I don't care about browser closing either. It just has to start a timer on page load and then reset that timer every time the user performs any action (click/type/etc)

Comment: I think this whole thing is over complicating it. If you really want, on the login page, see if they are here because the ticket has expired. If so, show a message saying "Your login has expired". So at least they know.

Answer (score 3):

You have couple of different aspects that  you need to consider here. First of all, what happens if the user just closes the browser or if the computer the person is using dies? If the user visits the page within 30 minutes, should the person still be logged in?

Let's say that the user should be logged in for 30 minutes, no matter what. The easiest way to start is to set a cookie timeout on an authentication cookie. Remember to update the timeout when each page refreshes. And use a jQuery timer to check if the cookie is still valid or not, or just keep track of the users login time.

So, [jQuery timers](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers), you could on each page load refresh the cookie and then just check if the timer/delay executes, if so, remove the cookie and display a modal box.

There's tons of ways of doing this, using the timers are one way.

```
$(this).oneTime(1800 , function() {
    location.href='/logout'; // redirects to logout page.
});
```

Another aproach is to use server side checking for this, but you will not get the model box for this, as I said, there are tons of ways, it all depends on your preferences.

Comment: I'm only worried about idle.  I just want to automatically call the /logout action if they are idle for 30 mins.  So using page load is not useful because that does not happen when someone is idle.

Comment: I've updated the answer. In the current jquery, when 30 minuts ( 1800 seconds ) have passed, you are redirected to logout. If you want a grown-effect, look into BlockUI ( http://jquery.malsup.com/block/ )

Comment: Yes but that does not restart the time every time the user interacts with the page.  Instead they will be logged out every 30 mins.  It has to be after 30 mins of inactivity.

Comment: It depends on your entire architecture, you need to "reset" the timer if the user interacts somehow. "Inactivity" is, in my eyes, as soon as a request is processed until a new request is started. So, once you start a new request, remove the timer and re-add it. See this question on how to remove&/stop timers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806094/stopping-and-removing-jquery-timers

Comment: The majority of requests in my app are ajax so there are very few page loads. However I do have an .ajaxstart method that could possibly be used to detect "any activity"

Comment: Valid `'/logout'`for MVC ?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's very old question, but could be useful for someone looking for similar solution to log out user if they are idle for certain timeperiod

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3130/automatically-logout-when-user-is-idle-for-sometime

The link may disappear so here is the code -

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("body").on('click keypress', function () {
            ResetThisSession();
        });
    });



var timeInSecondsAfterSessionOut = 30; // change this to change session time out (in seconds).
    var secondTick = 0;

    function ResetThisSession() {
        secondTick = 0;
    }

    function StartThisSessionTimer() {
        secondTick++;
        var timeLeft = ((timeInSecondsAfterSessionOut - secondTick) / 60).toFixed(0); // in minutes
    timeLeft = timeInSecondsAfterSessionOut - secondTick; // override, we have 30 secs only 

        $("#spanTimeLeft").html(timeLeft);

        if (secondTick > timeInSecondsAfterSessionOut) {
            clearTimeout(tick);
            window.location = "/Logout.aspx";
            return;
        }
        tick = setTimeout("StartThisSessionTimer()", 1000);
    }

    StartThisSessionTimer();
```

Comment: window.location = "/Logout.aspx"; This line is not for MVC and artical it self is for ASP.Net.

Comment: you could replace it with  -  $.redirectPost('@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")');

Comment: i merely copied code from the link (referenced above)

Comment: @NareshRavlani, for mvc use 
    window.location = "/Home/LogOff";